# issuing Netsh command from Delphi program

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, netsh

I am trying to capture the Device ID of an AirCard.  I am using the following code with the intentions of storing the results in a text file (imei.txt) that I store in the Temp folder and loop through the contents, looking for DEVICE ID.

The problems is that it only writes "The following command was not found: mbn show interface." to the file.

I have tested the Netsh command from the command line and it returns what I would expect.

```
    xs1 := CreateOleObject('WSCript.Shell');
    xs1.run('%comspec% /c netsh mbn show interface > "' + IMEIFileName +
      '"', 0, true);
```

It is failing to process the NetSh command properly.  Am I passing it through the Comspec correctly?  It seems to not run the "NetSh" command and acts as if I am running "mbn" from the command prompt.

Thanks

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Win.ComObj, ShlObj,     Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetAirCardInformation;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    IMEI: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetAirCardInformation;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.GetAirCardInformation;
var
  xs1 : OleVariant;
  IMEIFileName: String;
  IMEIStrings: TStringList;
  I: Integer;

  function GetSpecialFolder(const CSIDL: Integer): string;
  var
    RecPath: PWideChar;
  begin
    RecPath := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
    try
      FillChar(RecPath^, MAX_PATH, 0);
      if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, RecPath, CSIDL, false) then
        result := RecPath
      else
        result := '';
    finally
      StrDispose(RecPath);
    end;
  end;

begin
  IMEI := '';
  IMEIFileName := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA) + '\Temp\imei.txt';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('IMEIFileName: ' + IMEIFileName);
  try
    if FileExists(IMEIFileName) then
      DeleteFile(IMEIFileName);

    xs1 := CreateOleObject('WSCript.Shell');
    xs1.run('%comspec% /c netsh mbn show interface > "' + IMEIFileName +
      '"', 0, true);

    if FileExists(IMEIFileName) then
    begin
      IMEIStrings := TStringList.Create;
      IMEIStrings.LoadFromFile(IMEIFileName);
      IMEIStrings.NameValueSeparator := ':';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('IMEIStrings Count: ' + intToStr(IMEIStrings.Count));
      for I := 0 to IMEIStrings.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(IMEIStrings.text);
        if (Uppercase(Trim(IMEIStrings.Names[I])) = 'DEVICE ID') then
        begin
          IMEI := Trim(IMEIStrings.Values[IMEIStrings.Names[I]]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add('IMEI:' + IMEI);
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;

  except
    IMEI := '';
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('process complete');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why are you using the WShell COM object to invoke `cmd.exe`? Use `CreateProcess()` instead. The error message means `netsh` itself does not recognizing the `mbn show interface` command. What system are you running on? Why are you using `netsh` at all? Windows has a [Mobile Broadband API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271.aspx), use [`WwanEnumerateInterfaces()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313190.aspx) or [`IMbnInterfaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430416.aspx) to get a list of MBN interfaces.

Comment: thanks Remy.
Can you point me to an example of sorts?  All I can find is on MSDN.  I am on Windows 10 Pro and do not see a type library for this or anything related.

Comment: The TypeLibrary for the MBN interfaces is `mbnapi.tlb`.  I found a [Delphi unit for it](http://www.delphipraxis.net/189688-windows-mbn-api-fuer-delphi-xe-portieren.html) (`MbnApi.pas`) on the DelphiPraxis forum. You don't need a TypeLibrary to call the `Wwan...()` functions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the WShell COM object to run `cmd.exe`.  That is overkill.  You can use `CreateProcess()` instead.  However, when running `cmd.exe` programmably, you cannot redirect its output using the `>` operator, that only works in an actual command window.  You can instead use the `STARTUPINFO` structure to redirect the output to an anonymous pipe created with `CreatePipe()`, and then you can read from that pipe using `ReadFile()`.  No need to use a temp file at all.  MSDN has an article on this topic:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

There are plenty of examples floating around that demonstrate this technique in Delphi.

That being said, a better option is to not use `netsh` at all.  Windows 7 and later have a [Mobile Broadband API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271.aspx).  You can enumerate the MBN interfaces directly in your code.

For example, using the [`WwanEnumerateInterfaces()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313190.aspx) function:

```
unit WwApi;

{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

interface

uses
  Windows;

const
  WWAN_STR_DESC_LENGTH = 256;

type
  WWAN_INTERFACE_STATE = (
    WwanInterfaceStateNotReady,
    WwanInterfaceStateDeviceLocked,
    WwanInterfaceStateUserAccountNotActivated,
    WwanInterfaceStateRegistered,
    WwanInterfaceStateRegistering,
    WwanInterfaceStateDeregistered,
    WwanInterfaceStateAttached,
    WwanInterfaceStateAttaching,
    WwanInterfaceStateDetaching,
    WwanInterfaceStateActivated,
    WwanInterfaceStateActivating,
    WwanInterfaceStateDeactivating
  );

  WWAN_INTF_OPCODE = (
    WwanIntfOpcodePin,
    WwanIntfOpcodeRadioState,
    WwanIntfOpcodePreferredProviders,
    WwanIntfOpcodeCurrentConnection,
    WwanIntfOpcodeProvisionedContexts,
    WwanIntfOpcodeActivateUserAccount,
    WwanIntfOpcodeVendorSpecific,
    WwanIntfOpcodeInterfaceObject,
    WwanIntfOpcodeConnectionObject,
    WwanIntfOpcodeAcState,
    WwanIntfOpcodeClearManualConnectState,
    WwanIntfOpcodeGetStoredRadioState,
    WwanIntfOpcodeGetRadioInfo,
    WwanIntfOpcodeHomeProvider
  );

  // I don't know the definition of this type!
  WWAN_STATUS = DWORD; //?

  WWAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = record
    fInitialized: BOOL;
    InterfaceState: WWAN_INTERFACE_STATE;
  end;

  PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO = ^WWAN_INTERFACE_INFO;
  WWAN_INTERFACE_INFO = record
    InterfaceGuid: TGuid;
    strInterfaceDescription: array[0..WWAN_STR_DESC_LENGTH-1] of WCHAR;
    InterfaceStatus: WWAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;
    ParentInterfaceGuid: TGuid;
    fIsAdditionalPdpContextInterface: BOOL;
  end;

  PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST = ^WWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  WWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST = record
    dwNumberOfItems: DWORD;
    pInterfaceInfo: array[0..0] of WWAN_INTERFACE_INFO;
  end;

function WwanOpenHandle(dwClientVersion: DWORD; pReserved: Pointer; var pdwNegotiatedVersion: DWORD; var phClientHandle: THandle): DWORD; stdcall;
function WwanCloseHandle(hClientHandle: THandle; pReserved: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
function WwanEnumerateInterfaces(hClientHandle: THandle; pdwReserved: PDWORD; var ppInterfaceList: PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST): DWORD; stdcall;
procedure WwanFreeMemory(pMem: Pointer); stdcall;
function WwanQueryInterface(hClientHandle: THandle; const pInterfaceGuid: TGuid; opCode: WWAN_INTF_OPCODE; pReserved: Pointer; var pdwDataSize: DWORD; var ppData: PByte; var pRequestId: ULONG; var pStatus: WWAN_STATUS): DWORD; stdcall;

implementation

const
  WwApiLib = 'WwApi.dll';

function WwanOpenHandle; external WwApiLib delayed;
function WwanCloseHandle; external WwApiLib delayed;
function WwanEnumerateInterfaces; external WwApiLib delayed;
procedure WwanFreeMemory; external WwApiLib delayed;
function WwanQueryInterface; external WwApiLib delayed;

end.
```

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetAirCardInformation;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    IMEI: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  WwApi;

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetAirCardInformation;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.GetAirCardInformation;
var
  dwNegotiatedVersion: DWORD;
  hClientHandle: THandle;
  pInterfaceList: PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  pInterface: PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO;
  I: DWORD;
begin
  IMEI := '';
  Memo1.Clear;
  try
    // The value of the first parameter is undocumented!
    // WlanOpenHandle() has a similar parameter, where 1
    // is for XP and 2 is for Vista+. Maybe it is the same
    // for WwanOpenHandle()?...
    //
    if WwanOpenHandle(2, nil, dwNegotiatedVersion, hClientHandle) = 0 then
    try
      if WwanEnumerateInterfaces(hClientHandle, nil, pInterfaceList) = 0 then
      try
        Memo1.Lines.Add('IMEIStrings Count: ' + IntToStr(pInterfaceList.dwNumberOfItems));
        if pInterfaceList.dwNumberOfItems > 0 then
        begin
          pInterface := @pInterfaceList.pInterfaceInfo[0];
          for I := 0 to pInterfaceList.dwNumberOfItems-1 do
          begin
            // use pInterface as needed...

            Memo1.Lines.Add('Desc:' + StrPas(pInterface.strInterfaceDescription));
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Intf:' + GUIDToString(pInterface.InterfaceGuid));

            // and so on ...

            Memo1.Lines.Add('');
            Inc(pInterface);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        WwanFreeMemory(pInterfaceList);
      end;
    finally
      WwanCloseHandle(hClientHandle, nil);
    end;
  except
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('process complete');
end;

end.
```

Alternatively, using the [`IMbnInterfaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430416.aspx) and [`IMbnInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430406.aspx) COM interfaces, which give you more detailed information:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetAirCardInformation;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    IMEI: string;
    PhoneNumber: string;
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  // I found the MbnApi.pas unit on the DelphiPraxis forum:
  //
  // http://www.delphipraxis.net/1342330-post2.html
  //
  // It is too large to post here on StackOverflow!
  // Otherwise, you can import the mbnapi.tlb TypeLibrary yourself...
  //
  MbnApi, ActiveX, ComObj;

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetAirCardInformation;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.GetAirCardInformation;
var
  Mgr: IMbnInterfaceManager;
  pInterfaceArray, pPhoneNumberArray: PSafeArray;
  pInterface: IMbnInterface;
  subscriber: IMbnSubscriberInformation;
  ReadyState: MBN_READY_STATE;
  lIntfLower, lIntfUpper: LONG;
  lPhoneNumLower, lPhoneNumUpper: LONG;
  I, J: LONG;
  wStr: WideString;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  try
    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_MbnInterfaceManager, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IMbnInterfaceManager, Mgr));
    OleCheck(Mgr.GetInterfaces(pInterfaceArray));
    try
      OleCheck(SafeArrayGetLBound(pInterfaceArray, 1, lIntfLower));
      OleCheck(SafeArrayGetUBound(pInterfaceArray, 1, lIntfUpper));
      for I = lIntfLower to lIntfUpper do
      begin
        OleCheck(SafeArrayGetElement(pInterfaceArray, I, pInterface));
        try
          // use pInterface as needed...

          OleCheck(pInterface.get_InterfaceID(wStr));
          try
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Interface ID:' + wStr);
          finally
            wStr := '';
          end;

          OleCheck(pInterface.GetReadyState(ReadyState));
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Ready State:' + IntToStr(Ord(ReadyState)));

          OleCheck(pInterface.GetSubscriberInformation(subscriber));
          try
            OleCheck(subscriber.Get_SubscriberID(wStr));
            try
              Memo1.Lines.Add('Subscriber ID: ' + wStr);
            finally
              wStr := '';
            end;

            OleCheck(subscriber.Get_SimIccID(wStr));
            try
              Memo1.Lines.Add('Sim ICC ID: ' + wStr);
            finally
              wStr := '';
            end;

            OleCheck(subscriber.Get_TelephoneNumbers(pPhoneNumberArray));
            try
              OleCheck(SafeArrayGetLBound(pPhoneNumberArray, 1, lPhoneNumLower));
              OleCheck(SafeArrayGetUBound(pPhoneNumberArray, 1, lPhoneNumUpper));
              for J = lPhoneNumLower to lPhoneNumUpper do
              begin
                OleCheck(SafeArrayGetElement(pPhoneNumberArray, J, wStr));
                try
                  Memo1.Lines.Add('Phone #:' + wStr);
                finally
                  wStr := '';
                end;
              end;
            finally
              SafeArrayDestroy(pPhoneNumberArray);
            end;
          finally
            subscriber := nil;
          end;

          // and so on...

          Memo1.Lines.Add('');
        finally
          pInterface := nil;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      SafeArrayDestroy(pInterfaceArray);
    end;
  except
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('process complete');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Remy,
I tried using the WwApi  approach but I am unable to tease out the phone no or device ID.  That is all my client wants. 
I have a batch file that has the 2 lines below
netsh mbn show interfaces > "imei.txt"
netsh mbn show readyinfo="Mobile Broadband Connection">pno.txt"
It does just what I want but not when I call it from Delphi.  I have used both ShellExe and CreateProcess, with and without Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection but always end up in the same place.  It seems to run the NetSh but does not recognize the rest of the line.  I just want the data

Comment: `IMbnInterface` provides the information you are looking for, in its `ReadyState` and `SubscriberInformation` properties. If you insist on using netsh, you can't use the `>` operator for file redirection with `ShellExecute()`/`CreateProcess()`. You have to use pipe redirection, as shown in the MSDN article I linked you to. Do not use a temp file at all.

Comment: Okay, I am back to using WwApi but I can't find my way to ReadyState or SubscriberInformation.  I am lost like a ball in the high weeds.  All I want to do is get my client the aircard phone No. and device ID.  Every route seems to be a dead end.

Comment: Read my earlier comment again. I did not say `WwApi`, I said [`IMbnInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430406.aspx). Did you read the `IMbnInterface` documentation I linked to? `IMbnInterface` provides all kinds of information. I have updated my example.

Comment: I am unable to copy the mbnApi wrapper. The text is corrupted, about two thirds down. 
And it will not let me download the link, even though I am a registered user.  I cannot find the mbnapi.tlb on any of my machines, so as to generate a mbnapi wrapper myself.
Where can I find that type library?

Comment: The *full* text of `MbnApi.pas` is available at the URL I provided in my answer (it is too large to post on StackOverflow).  The text is NOT corrupted or truncated when I view it.  If you want to import `mbnapi.tlb` yourself, and it is not already on your machine, then you will likely have to download a Windows SDK from Microsoft.

Comment: Finally got it working.
Got the wrapper after opening in a different browser.  
Had to add comObj and fix the For loops but otherwise, it works.
Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117839/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-meta-mussel).